# Protect against nil in for loop

Tags: swift, loops, option-type

I've been getting this error...

`[2017-02-27 15:11:23] NONE us us_crdrscrdrsge NONE
        [2017-02-27 15:11:23] brea crdrs crdrs_ar united states
        [2017-02-27 15:11:23] brea crdrs crdrs_daz1 united states
        [2017-02-27 15:11:23] brea crdrs crdrs_dev united states
        [2017-02-27 15:11:23] brea crdrs crdrs_devgen united states
        [2017-02-27 15:11:24] NONE us us_ctabscaninv NONE
        [2017-02-27 15:11:24] NONE us us_ctabscanstmt NONE
        fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        2017-02-27 15:11:24.111276 Mobile[647:47234] fatal error: 
        unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

How can I protect against nil values in this for loop:

```

```
  let apResults = realm.objects(DestinationNoEnum.self).
           filter("destinationRegionCode = 'ap'")


  for aps in apResults {
        autoreleasepool {
        print("\(aps.destinationCity) \(aps.destinationCode) 
         \(aps.destinationName) \(aps.destinationCountry)")
        }}
```

the apResults array is created via a realm query. There's like 1000 entries in the db.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu looks like it has two good answers. Either explicitly check if aps != nil , or use their example for optional biding

Comment: Can you share the code for your `aps` entity? I don't think you should get back nil elements when iterating `apResults`.

Comment: Are you using implicitly unwrapped optionals, anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for aps in apResults where aps != nil {
    // do your things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
for case let aps? in apResults {
    // use aps which is ".some" value
}
```

Comment: A good answer should explain how it works and how it solves the issue in the question.

Comment: @HangarRash And that's exactly what it does.